# Lines of code counter

Tags: counters, statistics

Is there a way to automatically count the lines of code of a TeX document? And if yes, is there a way to include that in the document?

I would like to have something like "this document is n lines of code" somewhere in the document.

Comment: How is this meaningful? For example it doesn't matter if your input contains a paragraph of text in 10 lines of 80 characters each, or one line of 800 characters. Choosing one or the other is just personal preference, and/or how well your text editor works with long lines. The output will be identical either way.

Comment: @alephzero long lines count as one line still if there's no linebreak. I would need it for examples but it doesn't really matter in my opinion. I know similar tools exist for some programming languages so I was interested in knowing whether this existed for LaTeX too.

Comment: "long lines count as one line still if there's no linebreak" - that's what I said :) If what you really want to do is number the lines in an example so you can refer to them, use the `lineno` package (but that isn't the question you asked!)

Answer (score 4):

TeX has an internal counter `\inputlineno` which is used when printing error messages, etc.

If you include `\the\inputlineno` on the last line of your document, you should get pretty close to the number of lines in a file, though it may be off by one.

If you have multiple files in your project, you will have to add up the total number of lines yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is line \the\inputlineno

Some text

The last line is (almost!) \the\inputlineno
\end{document}
```

outputs "This is line 4" and "The last line is (almost!) 8" - it didn't count the `\end{document}` on line 9, unsurprisingly.